# SQL GROUP BY ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended --> Error at offset: 498

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Query shows duplicate names so I'm trying to group them so that it won't show me duplicate results. But it's giving me errors.

```
    Select 
TRIM( S90T1.fname)||'  '||(S90T1.lname)  "_CoWorker" ,L16T3.partno,l16T3.shortl62,L16T3.partrev,L16T3.ordno,L16T40.reascode ||'('|| Trim( E10T1.ma_desc)||')' "_reascode",L16T3.datreg "_Date"

 from L16T40, L16T3, S90T1, E10T1


where L16T3.ordno=L16T40.ordno 
and L16T3.logguser= S90T1.uname
and L16T40.reascode=E10T1.reascode
and  L16T3.L16lcode = 45
and  L16T3.datreg > @('DAYS',#DATE)
and L16T40.reascode != 0

ORDER BY 
"_Date" DESC

GROUP BY 
"_CoWorker"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things. First, `ORDER BY` should follow `GROUP BY`. Second, you can't use a column alias in `GROUP BY`. But I don't know why you're using `GROUP BY` at all, I don't see any aggregate functions. If you're getting duplicate records, and want to avoid them, then use `DISTINCT`. Last, I don't know what this line is a reference to: `and L16T3.datreg > @('DAYS',#DATE)`. Are you maybe borrowing syntax from another RDBMS? I have a hunch that perhaps you want `TRUNC(SYSDATE)`, which will give everything from the current day:

```
Select DISTINCT TRIM( S90T1.fname) || '  ' || (S90T1.lname)  "_CoWorker" 
     , L16T3.partno,l16T3.shortl62
     , L16T3.partrev,L16T3.ordno,L16T40.reascode ||'('|| Trim( E10T1.ma_desc)||')' "_reascode"
     , L16T3.datreg "_Date"
  from L16T40, L16T3, S90T1, E10T1
 where L16T3.ordno = L16T40.ordno 
   and L16T3.logguser = S90T1.uname
   and L16T40.reascode = E10T1.reascode
   and L16T3.L16lcode = 45
   and L16T3.datreg >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) -- @('DAYS',#DATE) ?
   and L16T40.reascode != 0
 ORDER BY "_Date" DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JOIN` instead of `,` Comma to join table.

You can't `ORDER BY` the alias name.

I think you might not use `GROUP BY`,There isn't any aggregate function in your query.

You can try to use `DISTINCT` on subquery.

```
Select 
    S90T1._CoWorker,
    L16T3.partno,
    l16T3.shortl62,
    L16T3.partrev,
    L16T3.ordno,
    L16T40.reascode ||'('|| Trim( E10T1.ma_desc)||')' "_reascode",
    L16T3.datreg "_Date"
FROM 
    L16T40 
    INNER JOIN  L16T3 ON L16T3.ordno=L16T40.ordno 
    INNER JOIN  
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT TRIM( S90T1.fname)||'  '||(S90T1.lname)  "_CoWorker",uname
        FROM S90T1
    ) S90T1 ON L16T3.logguser= S90T1.uname
    INNER JOIN  E10T1 ON L16T40.reascode=E10T1.reascode
where 
     L16T3.L16lcode = 45
and  L16T3.datreg > @('DAYS',#DATE)
and  L16T40.reascode != 0
ORDER BY 
    L16T3.datreg DESC
```

Comment: I tried using this and replacing the S90T1._CoWroker to S90T1.fname, .... However it loads all names and shows the same values for the other columns. Thanks

Comment: Could you show some sample data from `S90T1` table?

Comment: Sorry this is all I can provide... Columns Database Names : uname , stscreen,utype,alias,fname,lname

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` should be after `GROUP BY`.

General Structure of a Query:

```
select ..., ROWNUM
  from t
 where <where clause>
 group by <columns>
having <having clause>
 order by <columns>;
```

Correct Query:

```
Select 
TRIM( S90T1.fname)||'  '||(S90T1.lname) AS CoWorker ,L16T3.partno,l16T3.shortl62,L16T3.partrev,L16T3.ordno,L16T40.reascode ||'('|| Trim( E10T1.ma_desc)||')' AS reascode,L16T3.datreg AS Dte
from L16T40, L16T3, S90T1, E10T1

where L16T3.ordno=L16T40.ordno 
and L16T3.logguser= S90T1.uname
and L16T40.reascode=E10T1.reascode
and  L16T3.L16lcode = 45
and  L16T3.datreg > @('DAYS',#DATE)
and L16T40.reascode != 0

GROUP BY 
CoWorker

ORDER BY 
Dte DESC
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response however im getting this error
Error when executing Sql
ORA-00904: "_CoWorker": invalid identifier
--> Error at offset: 486

Comment: Remove Double quotes from the `_CoWorker` as well as `_Date`  @Nixon

Comment: @Nixon If you find it useful please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Error when executing Sql
ORA-00911: invalid character
--> Error at offset: 451

Comment: Error when executing Sql
ORA-00904: "COWORKER": invalid identifier
--> Error at offset: 482

Comment: `Group by TRIM( S90T1.fname)||'  '||(S90T1.lname)`  you can't use aliases `coWorker` in the group by; only the order by.  It has to do with order of operations the SQL engine goes though.  First from's and joins, then where's there group by then select then having then order by.  So SQL order of operation doesn't flow top down.  (at least in most engines)  mySQL and a few others behave slightly differently.  So the alias isn't in scope at the time the group by is being evaluated; thus the error.

Comment: Hi @xQbert I have tried using that `Group by TRIM( S90T1.fname)||' '||(S90T1.lname)` but getting an error not a GROUP BY Expression.

Comment: odd.. if works in the select here, it should work in the group by.  Eliminate the leading space maybe after the trim(?  in both the select and the group by?.. but why do you need a group by at all?  no aggregation... use `distinct` in the select instead?